# Trying to Import Data from Several URLs but Always Stuck on the First URL

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I guess I am going down the wrong track, and now I'm really off course.  I am trying to loop through 93 URLs and import data from each.  Here is the code that I am testing.

```
Sub Web_Table()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    lngRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To 93
    
        objIE.Navigate "https://etfdb.com/screener/#tab=returns&page=" & i
    
        Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'wait for java script to load
        
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
        With HTMLDoc.body
            Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
            For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
                For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                    For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                    Next lngCol
                Next lngRow
                ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
            Next lngTable
        End With
        
        Debug.Print i
        lngRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
    Next i
    
    objIE.Quit
    
End Sub
```

I am expecting to see this from the first URL:

```
Symbol  ETF Name    1 Week  4 Week  YTD 1 Year  3 Year  5 Year  Returns Rating
SPY SPDR S&P 500 ETF    -2.44%  7.19%   -2.19%  10.36%  36.10%  65.39%  
IVV iShares Core S&P 500 ETF    -2.46%  7.20%   -2.22%  10.48%  36.60%  65.41%  
VTI Vanguard Total Stock Market ETF -2.45%  7.88%   -2.58%  9.38%   33.94%  60.89%  
etc.
```

Then this from the second URL:

```
Symbol  ETF Name    1 Week  4 Week  YTD 1 Year  3 Year  5 Year  Returns Rating
VGT Vanguard Information Technology ETF 0.15%   8.00%   11.98%  34.51%  98.99%  168.56% 
XLK Technology Select Sector SPDR Fund  0.11%   7.44%   12.41%  36.64%  92.76%  161.90% 
etc.
```

And, next, this from the third URL:

```
Symbol  ETF Name    1 Week  4 Week  YTD 1 Year  3 Year  5 Year  Returns Rating
IXUS    iShares Core MSCI Total International Stock ETF -2.42%  9.27%   -10.66% -0.97%  4.29%   12.08%  
SCHF    Schwab International Equity ETF -2.48%  9.96%   -10.05% -0.66%  4.24%   11.43%  
etc.
```

For some bizarre reason, it seems to be stuck on the first URL, and it never goes to the second, third, etc.  I have the `objIE.Navigate` and the `Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy`.  What am I not seeing here?

Comment: if you modify the address in the addressbar that there is no change between "https://etfdb.com/screener/#tab=returns&page=1" and "https://etfdb.com/screener/#tab=returns&page=2" . It's working with the buttons on the bottom, so there might have some hidden variables there

Comment: If you refresh the page with CTRL-F5 the right page is loading, so there is probably some cache involved

Comment: Maybe playing with the flags of the navigate function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768360%28v%3dvs.85%29

Comment: I've found that the `objIE.Busy` call is not completely reliable, but have never looked into the reasons why. I find that replacing that section of code with `Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4 Or objIE.Busy` `DoEvents` `Loop` seems to do the trick. (Or you can remove the `objIE.Busy` part entirely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave enough time for page to have fully loaded. So look for something on the page that is only present when all desired data loaded and then test for that. I often test for number of rows in a results table for example.

Personally, if scraping is permitted, I would switch to xmlhttp to avoid the timing issue. You can alter the per_page and get more results with less requests. Here is an example:

You will need a json parser, such as jsonconverter.bas, to parse returned json into table if desired.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()
    Dim xhr As MSXML2.xmlhttp60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, body As String
    'required VBE (Alt+F11) > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library ;  Microsoft XML, v6 (your version may vary)

    Set xhr = New MSXML2.xmlhttp60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    body = "{""tab"":""returns"",""page"":pageNumber,""per_page"":1000}"

    With xhr
        Dim page As Long
        For page = 1 To 2
            .Open "POST", "https://etfdb.com/api/screener/", False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .send Replace$(body, "pageNumber", page)
            'debug.Print .Status
            ActiveSheet.Cells(page, 1) = .responseText
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I still can't get this working.  The page doesn't refresh for me.  I like your idea QHarr but all I get is some kind of JSON string, I think.  Does that actually work for you?  Also, wouldn't it be a GET instead of a POST?

Comment: It is a POST as you are updating to server. You need to parse that json with a json parser. It contains all the info you want. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jsonconverter.bas+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer it is very easy to parse as the json is not overly nested. There is a lovely answer by @omegastripes that you could also use which does the job fantastically.

Comment: I liked this way from @omegastripes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50156323/6241235

Answer (score 1):

I tried to test your code on my side and I found that it is working without any issue. It is generating the data for all 93 URLs.

I made this on Windows 10 64 bit OS with Excel 2016.

[image]

You can see the 'i' variable value that you have printed in the console.

[image]

I have seen this kind of issue with the VBA IE automation code get stuck on the ReadyState line.

To confirm this issue, you can try to put a breakpoint in your code and you will notice that code will continuously loop for ReadyState and it never ends.

If you try to run the same code on any other machine then you can notice that code will work fine. For example, the code is working for me.

Then also you can try to test with below code samples to see anyone of it works for you.

```
  With objIE
        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

  '----------------OR---------------------------------------

    Do While objIE.Busy = True
    Loop
  '----------------OR---------------------------------------
    Do While objIE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until objIE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    While objIE.Busy
         DoEvents
    Wend
```

If nothing works then try to test the Application.wait with some more seconds.

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

You can also make a test with Sleep function.

```
#If VBA7 Then ' Excel 2010 or later

    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)

#Else ' Excel 2007 or earlier

    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)

Sub demo()
   For i = 0 To 10
       DoEvents
           Sleep 1000
           Debug.Print i
   Next i
End Sub
```

Helpful thread reference:

[internetexplorer.application hangs on readystate=1 in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836625/internetexplorer-application-hangs-on-readystate-1-in-vba)